# Extracting a json value to a variable in zsh shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I'm trying to fetch the value of a currency from remote api, so I can later run it through some calculation. However, I cannot assign this value to a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

result = $(curl -s -X GET "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=SOME_KEY" | jq '.rates.GBP')

echo $result
```

This results in :

```
> ./script.sh:5: command not found: result
```

Comment: FYI `bash` and `zsh` are two different shells. Your shebang indicates you are using the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have spaces around an equals sign in a Bourne-like shell (e.g., sh, bash, zsh). What happens is that when zsh sees this line:

```
result = $(curl -s -X GET "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=SOME_KEY" | jq '.rates.GBP')
```

it thinks that `result` is the name of a command and that the equals sign and what follows it are the arguments of that command. To avoid this, just do this:

```
result=$(curl -s -X GET "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=SOME_KEY" | jq '.rates.GBP')
```

ETA: I do notice that the line number for the error is 5, not 3 as I would expect. I don't know if that's because of CR/LF line ending issues, if there's something missing from the script that you showed us, or whatnot.

Comment: wow, I feel silly now, can't believe I wasted an hour because of spaces..
Thank you!
(and as for the line count, it is in fact just an incorrect copy-paste)